# Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}r^n = 0$ if $0 < r < 1$ using that fact that $(1+h)^n \geq 1 + nh$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}r^n = 0$ if $0 < r < 1$ using $(1+h) \geq 1 + nh$. I know that I can let $r = \frac{1}{h+1}$ and substitute but I don't see how that gets me convergence to zero. Is there something I'm not getting here? Is there some way to bound this so I can apply the squeeze theorem?

Here is what I did:

Let $r = \frac{1}{h+1}$, it follows that:
$(\frac{1}{r})^n \geq 1 + n(\frac{1-r}{r})$ and so $1\geq r^{n-1}(r + (1-r)n)$.

Doing that gets me:

$0 < r^{n-1} \leq \frac{1}{r + (1-r)n}$, or in other words...

$0 < r^{n} \leq \frac{r}{(1-r)n + r} < \frac{r}{(1-r)n}$. Can I use the squeeze theorem here?

Answer (score 1):

For $0 < r < 1$ you have in fact $r= \dfrac{1}{1+h}$ for some $r > 0$. Hence $r^n= \dfrac{1}{(1+h)^n} \le \dfrac{1}{1 + nh} < \epsilon$ for $n \ge n_0$.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm overthinking it. What about what I did above? Is that valid?

Comment: It is correct, but too complicated. (1) You correctly calculate $h = \frac{1-r}{r}$, but that is irrelevant. (2) With that value of $h$ you have $\frac{r}{r + (1-r)n} = \frac{1}{1 + nh}$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say $\frac{r}{(1-r)n + r} < \frac{r}{(1-r)n}$? I can use $\epsilon-N$ to prove that $\frac{r}{(1-r)n}$ converges to zero - and then apply squeeze theorem. I can do that right?

Comment: I totally understand your proof I'm just trying to understand this from every angle.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But again it is easier to work with $h$. You can also use $(1+h)^n \ge 1 +nh > nh$ to conclude that $r^n < \frac{1}{nh}$.

Comment: Definitely. Thanks!